# Find number of consecutive elements before value changes (MATLAB)

Tags: matlab

I have a (row)vector of some size, containing the values 1,2 and 3. They are in there in no 'specific' order, so a sample of the array would be [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3]. What I want to do is find the consecutive number of identical elements, but with some restrictions.

What I want is to make new arrays of which the elements denote:

- The number of consecutive 1's before it changes into a 2
- The number of consecutive 2's before it changes into a 1
- The number of consecutive 2's before it changes into a 3
- The number of consecutive 3's before it changes into a 2

So for the example I have given, the arrays would be

```
[4,2]
[3]
[2]
[]
```

I'm not sure how to tackle this. I can use the diff function to find where it changes sign, but then it'll be a little tough to figure out exactly what change has occured, right?

The method does not have to be super fast, as I only have to do this a few times for around 10^5 datapoints.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach will group things the way you specified in the question:

```
a=[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3]
b = diff(a)
c = find(b)
d = diff([0,c]);
type1 = d(b(c) == 1 & a(c) == 1);
type2 = d(b(c) == -1 & a(c) == 2);
type3 = d(b(c) == 1 & a(c) == 2);
type4 = d(b(c) == -1 & a(c) == 3);

type1 =
     4     2
type2 =
     3
type3 =   
     2
type4 =
   Empty matrix: 1-by-0
```

Comment: Yes, this does indeed seem to be doing what I needed. It's a bit opaque to me at first sight, but after looking at it for a while it's very clever. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad it worked!  Sorry I didn't have enough time to put in sufficient explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Use the standard procedure with [`diff`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to detect changes and run lengths, and then apply [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to group run lengths according to each pair of values before and after the change:

```
x = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3];
x = x.'; %'// easier to work with a column vector
ind = find(diff(x))+1; %// index of positions where x changes
%// To detect what change has ocurred, we'll use x(ind-1) and x(ind)
len = diff([1; ind]); %// length of each run
result = accumarray([x(ind-1) x(ind)], len, [], @(v) {v}); %// group lengths
```

Note the order within each result vector may be altered, as per `accumarray`.

In your example, this gives

```
>> result
result = 
     []    [2x1 double]     []
    [3]              []    [2]
>> result{1,2}
ans =
     2
     4
>> result{2,1}
ans =
     3
>> result{2,3}
ans =
     2
```

Comment: Thank you very much, a very nice approach! The ordering has some meaning for the purpose for which I'm using this, so the answer below works a bit better for me, but nevertheless a great solution.

Comment: Welcome! Yes, it's a pity that `accumarray` doesn't guarantee order

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will do the trick (although it's not very pretty)

```
a=[1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3];
d=diff(a);
deltas=(d~=0);
d12=[];d23=[];d32=[];d21=[];
last=0;
for i=1:length(a)-1
    if deltas(i)
        if a(i)==1&&a(i+1)==2
            d12=[d12,i-last];
            last=i;
        elseif a(i)==2&&a(i+1)==3
            d23=[d23,i-last];
            last=i;
        elseif a(i)==3&&a(i+1)==2
            d32=[d32,i-last];
            last=i;
        elseif a(i)==2&&a(i+1)==1
            d21=[d21,i-last];
            last=i;
        end

    end
end
```

Comment: Hm, it seems to go on longer than it should, as it's giving me errors saying that it's trying to access elements of deltas that don't exist. Don't immediately see what's wrong though..

Comment: Not sure. Try adding some print statements to keep track of what it's doing. for example put after the line if deltas(i): `fprintf('Starting element %d/%d',i,length(a));`

Comment: I fixed the out of range error, I forgot diff makes you lose an element since it requires 2 elements to compute. Also this does not handle the final edge case, Not sure how you would want to handle this but this code works as a simple example

Comment: That it doesn't take the final edge case into account is not a very big deal, so that's fine. Thank you for the answer, it definitely gets the job done.