# Count lengths of sequences of consecutive integers in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, run-length-encoding

I want to count all lengths of sequences of consecutive integers and return those as a vector.
For example, consider the vector: 
`x = [1 2 3 4 6 8 9 10 12 13];`

The lengths will be:

```
length([1 2 3 4]) = 4;
length([6]) = 1;
length([8 9 10]) = 3;
length([12 13]) = 2;
```

So, the result I want to generate is:

```
y = [4 1 3 2]
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/86420-find-a-series-of-consecutive-numbers-in-a-vector

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate, but it covers your question and more:
[printing consecutive numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21547239/printing-only-consecutive-numbers-from-an-array-in-matlab)

Comment: You are looking for the so called *run lengths* of `x-(1:length(x))`. So you can use this answer: [Run length encoding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348062/find-number-of-consecutive-elements-before-value-changes-matlab/23348808#23348808)

Comment: @knedlsepp, runs in RLE are usually considered to be sequences of identical values. The two things are of course close, but not identical. Just  to be precise.

Comment: @A.Donda: If you subtract `1:length(x)` the numbers previously consecutive will now be identical.

Comment: @knedlsepp, sure, as I said, "close". :-)

Comment: @A.Donda: But *run lenghts of `x-(1:length(x))`* is not only close, but exactly what we want...

Comment: @knedlsepp, true, one can look at it this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
y = diff(find(diff([nan ; x(:) ; nan]) ~= 1))
```

The inner `diff` looks for steps that are *not* +1 (sequence breaks), the `find` determines the corresponding positions (indices), the outer `diff` computes sequence lengths as differences between sequence break positions. The `nan`s are there to make sure that the sequence at the beginning and the sequence at the end of the vector are found, by inducing `diff` values different from 1.

Comment: `y = diff(find([0 diff(x) 0] ~= 1))` to avoid `NaNs`?

Comment: @Divakar, hmm, sure, but I wanted to avoid the assumption that there can't be a 0 (or -2, -1, ... for that matter) among the numbers. Nans don't really pose a problem, do they?

Comment: Alternatively, one could first do the inner diff and then prepend and append 1s, like in knedlsepps answer. Which, however, I find otherwise unnecessarily complicated...

Comment: It works for the small x vector, but I have a 542474 by 1 column vector, and I get the following error: 'Error using horzcat
Dimensions of matrices being concatenated are not consistent.'

Comment: I think it's funny that you find my answer overly complicated, as it basically the same thing: `diff, find, diff`... :-)

Comment: @user3611812, I just made an edit, now it can deal with column vectors.

Comment: @knedlsepp, the basic idea is the same, and the same of L. Mendo's answer you linked to. But there is no need for `1:numel(x)` and no need for two anonymous functions.

Comment: Well, I guess this won't be the case ever, but if ever any `NaN` ends up in `x`, but yeah won't be the case. I am just trying to think this should handle all kinds of data without throwing any error whatsoever.

Comment: @Divakar, even if there are nans in the data: `nan - nan` is again `nan` and therefore not the same as +1. Each nan in the data, at the beginning, end, or somewhere in the middle, appears as a sequence of length 1 in the output. Unless that is not the expected behavior, I think there's no problem.

Comment: @A.Donda: I don't see the harm in the anonymous functions. The runtime is pretty much the same and the functional programming style makes for a more self-documenting solution. Also you could consider it code-reuse if there already were some kind of built-in run length function.

Comment: This works as well. I also tried it before, but I put a complementary comma when defining my column vector, and I wasn't aware. Thank you as well.

Answer (score 2):

A small variation of [A. Donda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28071437/2586922):

1. Use [`diff`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) to detect differences larger than 1. This gives a `1` value at the *end* of each run.
2. Accumulate backwards (with [`cumsum`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html)) to assign a different numeric label to each run. Accumulation is done backwards because the `1` values in step 1 are at the end of each run, not at the beginning.
3. Compute run length with [`histc`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/histc.html).

Code:

```
y = [diff(x)>1 1];               %// step 1
y = cumsum(fliplr(y));           %// step 2
y = fliplr(histc(y, 1:y(end)));  %// step 3
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to accumulate *backwards*, though?

Comment: @A.Donda Because step 1 produces ones at the _end_ of each run. I'll edit to clarify

Answer (score 1):

This is equal to the *[run lengths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding)* of `x - (1:length(x))`. Therefore you could use:

```
runLengths = @(x) diff([0, reshape(find(x(1:end-1)~=x(2:end)),1,[]), numel(x)]);
sequenceCounts = @(x) runLengths(x(:)-(1:numel(x)).');
result = sequenceCounts(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = [1 2 3 4 6 8 9 10 12 13];

consecs = []; % empty vector to store answers
consec = 1; % initialize
for I=2:length(x)
    if x(I)==x(I-1)+1 % this one is consecutive with previous
        consec = consec+1;
    else % this one starts a new set of consecutives
        consecs(end+1) =  consec;
        consec = 1;
    end
end
consecs(end+1)=consec; % remember to include the last consecutives
display(consecs)
```

This is tested and it works.